# The provided cwd "/home/www/myproject" does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I used to map only one folder to my projects root folder as recommended in [Laravel 5.6](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/homestead#configuring-homestead).

Now, I mapped each folder to each separate project as recommended in [Laravel 6.x](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/homestead#configuring-homestead).

Now if I login into my VS with `vagrant ssh` and try `laravel new myproject` I get

> The provided cwd "/home/www/myproject" does not exist

If I create the folder beforehand, than I get

> Application already exists

If I install as root, then Laravel gets installed, but I can't find my project on my PC. I see it on my VS, buts it not on my hard-drive.

This is the config in my `Homestead.yaml`:

```
- map: ~/www/homestead/myproject # Path on my laptop
  to: /home/www/myproject #Path of VM
```

I find `/home/www/myproject` which I created on my VS, but `~/www/homestead/myproject` does not exist on my PC.

I did not have these issues when I was only mapping one folder. How can I fix this and create a new Laravel project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by installing Laravel command globally with composer on my PC. To do so, I had to install zip first:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-zip
```

Then I could install it globally

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

Which displayed

> Changed current directory to /home/adam/.config/composer

and I had to add this to my `~/.profile`:

```
PATH="$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

I reloaded profile in command with `source ~/.profile` and then I finally could install Laravel from my PC instead from the VM.